# Why is my python setter not being called?

Tags: python, validation, getter-setter

Can someone please help? I am new to python and have been staring at this problem for hours.

I have a person and a student class, and learning to validate the input with getters/setters. The person class takes in first name, last name, age, and gender, and all those are calling the setter correctly. When I get to the GPA in the student class, it won't call the setter and it keeps throwing an error because it's trying to add in the GPA to my student total before validating it. Please help! My code is below.

THIS CLASS IS WORKING CORRECTLY:

```py
class Person:
   'Common base class for all people'
   
   intPeopleCount = 0   
      
   def __init__(self, firstname, lastname, age, gender):
      self.firstname = firstname
      self.lastname = lastname
      self.age = age
      self.gender = gender
      Person.intPeopleCount += 1

   @property
   def firstname(self):
       return self.__firstname

   @property
   def lastname(self):
       return self.__lastname

   @property
   def age(self):
       return self.__age

   @property
   def gender(self):
       return self.__gender

   @firstname.setter 
   def firstname(self, firstname):
       if firstname == " ":
           raise Exception('Must input first name.')
       else:
           self.__firstname = firstname

   @lastname.setter
   def lastname(self, lastname):
       if lastname == " ":
           raise Exception('Must input last name.')
       else:
           self.__lastname = lastname

   @age.setter
   def age(self, age):
       if age == " ":
           raise Exception('Must input age.')
       if int(age) < 0:
           raise Exception('Age cannot be less than 0.')
       else:
           self.__age = age

   @gender.setter
   def gender(self, gender):
       if gender.lower() != 'female':
           if gender.lower() != 'male':
               raise Exception('Gender must be male or female.')
           else:
               self.__gender = gender
       else:
           self.__gender = gender
```

THIS IS THE CLASS THROWING ERRORS-
The GPA setter is not being called!!

```py
#Import Person Class
import PersonClass as person

class Student(person.Person):
    'Common base class for all students'

    intStudentCount = 0
    intFemaleCount = 0
    intMaleCount = 0
    dblGPATotal = 0
    intFemaleAgeTotal = 0
    intMaleAgeTotal = 0

    def __init__(self, firstname, lastname, age, gender, GPA):
        person.Person.__init__(self, firstname, lastname, age, gender)
        self.GPA = GPA

        if (gender == 'Male'):
            Student.intMaleCount += 1
            Student.intMaleAgeTotal += int(age)
        else:
            Student.intFemaleCount += 1
            Student.intFemaleAgeTotal += int(age)

        Student.dblGPATotal += GPA
        Student.intStudentCount += 1

        @property 
        def GPA(self):
            return self.__GPA

        @GPA.setter
        def GPA(self, GPA):
            if GPA == " ":
                raise Exception('Must input GPA.')
            elif GPA < 0:
                raise Exception('GPA must be 0.00 or higher.')
            elif GPA > 4.0:
                raise Exception('GPA must be 4.00 or lower.')
            else:
                self.__GPA = GPA
```

Thank you D:

Comment: The GPA setter never sets `self.__GPA`

Comment: I've edited my code but having the same problem.

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'float' and 'str' - It's trying to add the GPA but I have it set as empty, it's supposed to throw an exception and tell me I must input GPA.

Comment: That means that `GPA` is a string. You're not using the getter or setter on the line `Student.dblGPATotal += GPA`

Comment: How can I call it to use it on that line?

Comment: `self.GPA` instead of `GPA`.

Comment: Is that the line getting the error?

Comment: Is your indentation correct? The setter and getter methods shouldn't be inside the `__init__` method.

Comment: Yep, that's the line that's getting the error. You're saying change it to Student.dblGPATotal += self.GPA ? I've just tried it and the line is still getting the same error.

Comment: Why is `GPA` a string in the first place? Please show how you're calling this code.

Comment: Does your posted indentation match the actual code? The indentation of the getter and setter methods in `Student` are wrong.

Comment: They should be indented one level less, not nested inside the `__init__` method. That's making them ordinary functions, not class methods.

Comment: It was the indentation!!! It was inside the init method. *facepalm* It's working now! Thank you so much for your help!